# How to create a Hyperlink from a MySQL record set with PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hyperlink

I'm a complete beginner with HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL, and I am using XAMPP to run a local MySQL/Apache server for testing purposes. I decided to create a simple page as a learning exercise that will create a table with data read from a MySQL table.

I have a MySQL table with 2 columns: Title and link. The 'Title' column lists the name of a Steam game, while the 'link' column contains a link to the Steam store page for that game.

I have done some searching to get a basic idea of how to do this, and I've almost got it working, but for some reason the data from the 'Title' column is displayed horizontally instead of vertically.

I'm a brand new member so I can't post images yet, but here's a link to a screenshot to clarify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig3Wz.png

I want Far Cry 3 to be listed vertically underneath of //N.P.P.D. RUSH, but instead it is listed to the right.

and here is the code:

```
<body>

<h1>Steam</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','test1');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM steam ORDER BY Title');

echo '<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
</tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td><a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['Title'].'</a></td>';
}
echo '</table>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<a href="#" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">previous</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I know I'm overlooking something simple, but I'm too much of a beginner to know what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table row (`tr`) tags for each of the table data (`td`) elements?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['Title'].'</a></td></tr>';
}
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/table

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I overlooked that. I guess I'm getting in a bit over my head trying to mess with PHP and MySQL before I even have a stronger grasp on HTML.